# Is it possible to set borderless window mode?

Tags: mass-effect

I am playing Mass Effect again but there doesn't appear to be an option to enable a borderless window mode in either the game or the configuration utility, leaving the game running inside of a visible window.

Is it possible to set a borderless window mode either by editing one of the configuration files or using a third party utility or some kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) Script:

```
^!a::
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, a
WinMove, a, , 0, 0, 1680, 1050
return
```

When you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> it will make the currently active window borderless.

Replace `1680` and `1050` with the size you want the window to be.

Answer (score 1):

Mass Effect does not come with any support for borderless window mode.  The only way to do so is to use a third party utility such as [ShiftWindow](http://grismar.net/shiftwindow/).

There are also ways to do it with [autohotkey](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderless_fullscreen_windowed)

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't put ME into a borderless window for me, I get a similar effect with another utility that is meant to create borderless windows, I just end up with a window with a border...

Comment: @kalina you might be out of luck then, ME is a rather old game